# How to fix "make: 'all' is up to date error" while executing make command on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, makefile, ocr

I am currently running a code that runs OCR. I have linked 5 other programs with it. 
I must say that this is not my code, I have downloaded it from here https://github.com/PiotrKala/OCR?files=1

I renamed my makefile file with the mk extension. I also replaced a space character with tab between 'all' and 'main' and doing so fixed a 'make: Nothing to be done for 'all'' error.

```
CC=gcc
PTHREAD=-lpthread
CCFLAGS=-w

all:    main


main:
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -o main main.c LibBMP.c  skeleton.c extractor.c $(PTHREAD)

clean:
    rm main

test:
    ./main ../examples/sample.bmp
    @echo 
    cat output.txt
    @echo
    cat final.txt
```

I would say the expected result is for output.txt to open.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Why is my output.txt file not opening ?

Comment: @dublejin: why would it open? `make` executes `all` which depends only on `main`, which has nothing to do with `output.txt`.

Comment: `make` is used to walk down a dependency tree and check what needs to be done. If you don't have a dependency for a target, the target will not be touched. You can use `make test` if you want to make `test` target. Otherwise `all` target will be made

Comment: Okay. How do I make test the target ?

Answer (score 1):

The target name might be conflicting with your output filename.

Try adding this in the Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all main
```

`.PHONY` tells `Make` that the targets are not associated with files

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `cat output.txt` part to run then you should invoke the `test` target, like this:

```
make test
```

If you just do `make` then that will give the `all` target because that comes first in the makefile.

Answer (score 0):

> Nothing to be done for 'all'' error.

This could be normal if you have not changed any of the source files since the last time you built the program. You should probably show the exact commands you are using, and the exact output from the commands.

You should also add prerequisites to some of your rules. Once the program is built, the lack of prereqs means make won't be able to determine when a target is out of date. For example, editing `main.c` won't trigger a build. Maybe something like:

```
CC=gcc
PTHREAD=-lpthread
CCFLAGS=-w

all: main

main: main.c LibBMP.c skeleton.c extractor.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -o main main.c LibBMP.c  skeleton.c extractor.c $(PTHREAD)

clean:
    rm main

test: main
    ./main ../examples/sample.bmp
    @echo 
    cat output.txt
    @echo
    cat final.txt
```

---

This looks unusual. There is no variable called `CCFLAGS`.

```
main:
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) ...
```

Typically your recipe looks something like:

```
CFLAGS = -g -w
CCFLAGS = -I. $(CFLAGS)

main:
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CCFLAGS) ...
```

Using `CFLAGS` and `CCFLAGS` does two things. First, it provides a default value for `CFLAGS`. Second, it allows a user to override `CFLAGS` while providing required options though `CCFLAGS`.

Also see [GNU Make | 10.3 Variables Used by Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html) and [GNU Coding Standards | 7.2.3 Variables for Specifying Commands](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Command-Variables.html).